# Query to remove duplicates in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I need a single query without using CTE / `row_number` to remove duplicates based on the `ACTID` in SQL Server.

Table :

```
ACTID TRID CD DATE
-------------------
 1    1     0 12/04 - To be deleted 
 1    2     2 11/04 - To be deleted 
 1    3     4 10/04 - Do not delete 
 2    4     0 10/04 - To be deleted 
 2    5     2 11/04 - Do not delete 
 3    6     4 12/04 - Do not delete 
 3    7     4 11/04 - To be deleted
```

Conditions:

- Do not delete if CD = 4
- If CD in 0, 2 or 4, 4, keep the newest record
- If CD in 2, 4, delete 2

The output should consist of TRID's that needs to be deleted.

Able to get the required outcome using cte but unable to integrate it in Java jpa so looking for simpler approach without using cte/row_number.

Comment: why the no `ROW_NUMBER` restriction?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server 2000?

Comment: It is not working when used with Jpa native query.

Comment: @BrianStork I think the op meant that if there are 2 rows with CD values in (0,2) or both are 4, then keep the newest. If those rows have CD in (2,4), then delete the one that where CD = 2

Comment: You say `Do not delete if CD = 4` but the last row has a CD = 4 and `To be deleted`. So confusing.

Comment: that's because the other row also has a 4 value in it, so the newest should stay

Comment: @Brianstork- If there is 4 in CD value in a group keep it and delete others, if the value is other than 4, keep the newest and delete others.If there are multiple 4's keep the newest.

Answer (score 0):

Though the query seems messy it will do the trick.

```
create table myTable(ACTID int, TRID int, CD int, DATE varchar(5))
insert into myTable values( 1,    1,     0, '12/04');-- - To be deleted 
 insert into myTable values(1,    2,     2, '11/04');-- - To be deleted 
 insert into myTable values(1,    3,     4, '10/04');-- - Do not delete 
 insert into myTable values(2,    4,     0, '10/04');-- - To be deleted 
 insert into myTable values(2,    5,     2, '11/04');-- - Do not delete 
 insert into myTable values(3,    6,     4, '12/04');-- - Do not delete 
 insert into myTable values(3,    7,     4, '11/04');-- - To be deleted
```

Delete Query:

```
delete a from myTable a inner join myTable b 
  on (a.ACTID=b.ACTID and b.CD=4 and a.CD<4)
  or (a.ACTID=b.ACTID and b.CD=4 and a.TRID<>b.TRID and (a.CD=4 and b.CD=4) and a.DATE<b.DATE)
  or (a.ACTID=b.ACTID and b.CD=4 and a.TRID<>b.TRID  and((a.CD = 0 and b.CD =2)or(a.CD = 2 and b.CD =0)) and a.DATE<b.DATE)
  or (a.ACTID=b.ACTID and a.TRID<>b.TRID  and(a.CD in (0,2) and b.CD in (0,2)) and a.DATE<b.DATE)
    and not exists (select * from mytable m where m.ACTID=a.ACTID and m.CD=4)
```

select * from myTable

| ACTID | TRID | CD | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 4 | 10/04 |
| 2 | 5 | 2 | 11/04 |
| 3 | 6 | 4 | 12/04 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Wr9a8AFD)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my try:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #t(ACTID int, TRID int, CD int, DATE varchar(5))
INSERT INTO #t VALUES(1, 1, 0, '12/04')-- - To be deleted 
,(1, 2, 2, '11/04')-- - To be deleted 
,(1, 3, 4, '10/04')-- - Do not delete 
,(2, 4, 0, '10/04')-- - To be deleted 
,(2, 5, 2, '11/04')-- - Do not delete 
,(3, 6, 4, '12/04')-- - Do not delete 
,(3, 7, 4, '11/04');-- - To be deleted 
 
SELECT  *
FROM    #t t
WHERE   EXISTS(
        SELECT  1
        FROM    #t t2
        WHERE   t2.ACTID = t.actid
        AND (
            (t.cd <> 4 AND t2.cd = 4)
        OR  (t.cd = 4 AND t2.cd = 4 AND t2.DATE > t.date)
        OR  (t.cd <> 4 AND t2.cd <> 4 AND t2.DATE > t.date)
        )
    )
```

It returns list of ids to remove by filtering out:

1. Those with CD <> 4 where exists a CD=4 row
2. Where exists another CD=4 row with later date
3. Those non CD=4 rows with lower dates than other non CD=4